# Using Sed to remove only first character in file name if it's alphabetical

Tags: linux, sed, cmd

I have bunch of files in a folder which I need to copy with another name in case, that if file first charcter is alphabetical, then remove this character and leave all other character asis either those are numbers, alphabeticals, special marks or what ever. So few exsapmles:

R123456.txt      --> should be copied as 123456.txt

Y1235465.jpeg    --> should be copied as 1235465.jpeg

736628487.txt    --> do nothing

I have used this command:

```
for file in * ; do cp  $file $(echo $file |sed 's/[A-Za-z]//g'); done
```

But this removes also file extensions which I would like to leave as is...

br
Jii

Comment: @PS only removing the `g` flag will remove the first letter of the extension for files with names containing only numbers.

Comment: @MCND ,true ,make sense.My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
s/^[A-Za-z]//
```

At the start of the buffer a single alphabetic character

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this;

```
 for file in * ; do cp -n $file $(echo $file |sed 's/^[A-Za-z]//') 2>/dev/null; done
```

> man cp ;  -n, --no-clobber
>                 do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
>
> 2>/dev/null : to drop any for "‘736628487.txt’ are the same file".

Eg:

```
user@host:/tmp/test/1$ ls
736628487.txt  R123456.txt  Y1235465.jpeg

user@host:/tmp/test/1$  for file in * ; do cp -n $file $(echo $file |sed 's/^[A-Za-z]//') 2>/dev/null; done

user@host:/tmp/test/1$ ls
123456.txt  1235465.jpeg  736628487.txt  R123456.txt  Y1235465.jpeg
```